# The connection between Tishrei and Tevet

Tags: calendar, fast-days, drush, hallel, months

Can anyone steer me towards resources which explore a connection or relationship between Tishrei and Tevet (I assume, on a mystical level). Both months have a fast day on the 10th day and the full hallel of Tevet seems to compensate for the lack of hallel on rosh chodesh Tishrei.

I'm not exactly sure if this question falls within scope and I'm unclear as to how to tag it since I am guessing about mysticism.